# in perl can I sort my output of a foreach loop according to keywords in the original string?

Tags: perl, sorting

I am working on a problem, and iterating through an array. I am new to perl, so sorry if this is something very obvious I am not seeing. 
I want to sort the output according to a keyword in the original string. As I have two foreach loops that give me something like this:

```
[blup]
[ich]
[du]
[er]
[sie]
[es]

something something something

somethingelse something else something else
```

I want to sort it like that though according to a keyword in the original string where the substrings have been extracted from:

```
[blup blup]
[ich]
something something something

[er]
[sie]
[es]
something else something else something else
```

Thank you for your help!

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# perl -d ./perl_debugger.pl


use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Slurp;


my @a_linesorig;
my @solution;

my $line;

my $str;
my $grab;
my $s;
my $rs;
my $capture;



open(my $fh, "<", "output.txt")
    or die "cannot open < output.txt: $!";

$line = read_file('output.txt');

$line = read_file('output.txt');
@a_linesorig = split( /\*/, $line);
@solution = split( /\bsolution\b/, $line);

close $fh
    or die "can't close file: $!";

my $filename = 'neu.txt';   
open(my $fh1, '>', $filename)
    or die "can't open file: $!";

foreach $str (@a_linesorig)  {

    if ($str =~ (/\[(.*?)\]/)) {

        print ($fh1 "content bracket: $1\n\n");

    }
}

foreach $str (@a_linesorig)  {

    if ($str =~ /\brewrites\b([^\|]+)((\bcpu\b))*/g) {  

        print ($fh1 "decision: $&\n\n");

    }
}


close $fh1
    or die "can't close file: $!";
```

Comment: show actual sample input (not just existing output) and desired output or no one will be able to figure out what you mean.

Comment: Any reason you're not using an [existing](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template) templating system?

Comment: the sample input is very very tedious and long i can provide it but it is a mess that is why i have to use perl, however I would say the solutions should be sorted according to the string being split at the keyword solution# e.g. solution1, solution2 etc. hence one [ich] [du] something something should be sorted according to the keyword solution.

Comment: regarding the existing templating system, which one are you specifically referring to in my case?

Comment: i tried adding the raw data but it is too long, even if i only put one snippet that would make sense here...

Answer (score 0):

As you are calculating your results you could store them in a hash at the end you can iterate through your hash (by sorted keys)

This is unchecked pseudo-perl but the concept is:

Define a hash:

```
%hash
```

When you store the entry you would do

```
$hash{$key-that-you-want-to-sort-by} = $Thing-that-you-want-to-print
```

Then when you are done you could loop through your keys

```
for (my $key (sort keys $hash)) {
print $key{$hash};
}
```

Comment: is $ key that i want to sort by a regex? and $ thing that I want to print should be the result of the foreach loop but sorted?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, I would say that you should employ a hash, who's keys are the words in the original string, and who's values are the ordering that you want to preserve.

Then, afte ryou're processed your input, you will look over the keys of the hash, sorted by your ordering, and print you results for each word inside the loop.